# Dynamic Resource Loading Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to find a way to open resources whose name is determined at runtime only.

More specifically, I want to have a XML that references a bunch of other XML files in the application apk. For the purpose of explaining, let's say the main XML is `main.xml` and the other XML are `file1.xml`, `file2.xml` and `fileX.xml`. What I want is to read `main.xml`, extract the name of the XML I want (`fileX.xml`), for example, and then read `fileX.xml`. The problem I face is that what I extract form `main.xml` is a string and I can't find a way to change that to `R.raw.nameOfTheFile`.

Anybody has an idea?

I don't want to:

- regroup everything in one huge XML file
- hardcode main.xml in a huge switch case that links a number/string to the resource ID

Comment: i faced a similar problem but I am not getting any accepted answer for this. Can anybody start bounty for this question?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I haven't used it with raw files or xml layout files, but for drawables I use this:

```
getResources().getIdentifier("fileX", "drawable","com.yourapppackage.www");
```

to get the identifier (R.id) of the resource. You would need to replace drawable with something else, maybe `raw` or `layout` (untested).

Comment: Thanks for the answer that work great. For those in the same case [here is a good explanation on the subject](http://www.anddev.org/tinytut_-_get_resources_by_name__getidentifier_-t460.html) (once I had the name of the function it was simple): `getResources().getIdentifier("fileX", "raw", application package);`

Comment: Dead link? @JasonRogers Ah, nvm - it should be http://www.anddev.org/tinytut_-get_resources_by_name__getidentifier-t460.html

Comment: no not dead link casperOne removed my post and changed it to a comment without taking the time to do it correctly (aka broken link) here is the link: http://www.anddev.org/tinytut_-_get_resources_by_name__getidentifier_-t460.html

Answer (score 25):

I wrote this handy little helper method to encapsulate this:

```
public static String getResourceString(String name, Context context) {
    int nameResourceID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "string", context.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
    if (nameResourceID == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No resource string found with name " + name);
    } else {
        return context.getString(nameResourceID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very useful, thanks, but not ever we would want a string. sometimes a stream would be better.

Answer (score 7):

There is another method:

```
int drawableId = R.drawable.class.getField("file1").getInt(null);
```

According to [this blog](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.co.il/2009/12/dynamically-retrieving-resources-in.html) it's 5x times faster than using getIdentifier.