# Is there anything similar to Android's resource system on a smaller scale?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, resources, android-resources

I'm writing an Android app where I have a ton of variables that I need to access in a particular activity (basically, a "data model" for a small game of sorts). Currently, I'm storing them all in one huge "container" class so I can easily refer to them without polluting my activity class. Example:

```
public class Model
{
    private int a;
    private String b;
    private float c;

    ...

    public int getA()
    {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(int a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String getB()
    {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(String b)
    {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public float getC()
    {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(float c)
    {
        this.c = c;
    }

    ...
}
```

As you can see, they're of different types, and all have getters and setters. But it's getting cumbersome storing them like this. I'd also like to iterate over groups of the variables, but with this flat getter/setter format I can't really do that.

I'm aware of Android's resource system, but it doesn't seem suitable for this, because the variables are not meant to be app-wide/global. They only exist for the life of this particular activity, and are programmatically generated each time the activity starts.

I was thinking of putting them all into a `Map<String, Object>` structure, where I could reference each variable via a String key. This would remove the need to have a container class with lots of getters and setters, since I could just call `put` or `get` on the map. But then whenever I'd want to get a value from the map, I'd have to cast to the expected type. I don't like the sound of that.

Anyone got a better solution? Is there something similar to Android's resource system that can be used on a smaller, more temporary scale?

Comment: If you make the class and variables static you can access the variables everywhere. Not sure if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, if these are meant to model the state of the Activity, you haven't just defined actual classes for each model object. That would be my suggestion. You're taking a very C-like procedural approach here with just dumping them in a single class together. Also, since your code doesn't show static getters and setters, you must be creating and accessing the container class somehow, no? Based on this small snippet and without more context it's hard to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a custom xml resource file for each activity.  These files are stored in the /xml folder at the same level as the /src folder.  Use the Resources class to load them.

Or take a look at this issue: [Dynamic Resource Loading Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648942/dynamic-resource-loading-android)