# Declaring button variables as an array with a for loop android

Tags: java, android, arrays, variables, for-loop

I managed to create buttons in a for loop and saw no reason why not to declare my varibles inside it too. Unfortunately eclipse only identifies the "bt" and doesn't want to replace my [i] with the number it represents in the loop and as a result find the correct id in my layout. Any thoughts on how to make this work? I'm also greatful for any other solution as beatiful as mine, which doesn't work ;)

```
Button [] bt = new Button[6];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start_layout);

    bt[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt0);
    bt[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);//This is what i'm trying to replace
    bt[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt2);
    bt[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt3);
    bt[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt4);
    bt[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt5);


    for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        final int b = i;
        bt [i] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt[i]);    <----//Whith this
        bt [i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Start.this, MainActivity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("players", b);
                startActivity(myIntent);

                //startActivity(new Intent(Start.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: `bt[i]` will be replaced with `bt[1]` and not `bt1` for `i = 1`. You can't use variable like that.

Comment: @RohitJain that's why OP asks the question.

Comment: here's one solution for your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648942/dynamic-resource-loading-android

Comment: @RohitJain Thanks for clearifying what the bt[i] really does!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would do the following:

```
private static final int[] idArray = {R.id.bt0, R.id.bt1, R.id.bt2, R.id.bt3, R.id.bt4, R.id.bt5};

private Button[] bt = new Button[idArray.length];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start_layout);

    for (int i=0; i<idArray.length; i++) {
        final int b = i;
        bt [b] = (Button)findViewById(idArray[b]); // Fetch the view id from array
        bt [b].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Start.this, MainActivity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("players", b);
                startActivity(myIntent);

                //startActivity(new Intent(Start.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

If you want to add or remove buttons, just add it to `idArray` and all other things are dynamic already.

Comment: Simple enough to understand and indeed beautiful. I'll give it a try as soon as I start my comp. tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

I think if you have group of similar buttons - they all placed inside 1 parent on layout (LinearLayout or RelativeLayout or something else). You can take get parent and retrieve all children. This way you don't need to specify id for each button.

```
ViewGroup buttonsView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.buttons);
List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
for (int i = 0; i < buttonsView.getChildCount(); i++) {
  buttons.add((Button) buttonsView.getChildAt(i));
}
```

Also you can store button's number in it's tag so you don't need to create `final int` variables:

```
ViewGroup buttonsView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.buttons);
List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Start.this, MainActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("players", (Integer) v.getTag());
        startActivity(myIntent);
        //startActivity(new Intent(Start.this, MainActivity.class));
    }
};
for (int i = 0; i < buttonsView.getChildCount(); i++) {
  Button button = (Button) buttonsView.getChildAt(i);
  button.setTag(i);
  button.setOnClickListener(listener);
  buttons.add(buttons);
}
```

Comment: Just want to clarify, this only works if the `ViewGroup` contains nothing but all the buttons. It cannot contains any other childs.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to awnser my question Nikita, but it's a bit beyond my understanding since I'm quite new to programming.