# How to read file from res/raw by name

Tags: android, file-io, resources

I want to open a file from the folder **res/raw/**. 
I am absolutely sure that the file exists.
To open the file I have tried

```
File ddd = new File("res/raw/example.png");
```

The command

```
ddd.exists();
```

yields **FALSE**. So this method does not work.

Trying

```
MyContext.getAssets().open("example.png");
```

**ends up in an exception with getMessage() "null".**

Simply using

```
R.raw.example
```

is not possible because the filename is only known during runtime as a string.

Why is it so difficult to access a file in the folder /res/raw/ ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic Resource Loading Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648942/dynamic-resource-loading-android)

Comment: Why is it only known at runtime as a string? Could you keep a mapping between the strings and the IDs?

Comment: Read the docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: Thank you for the links. I will give a correct solution as a separate answer.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

With the help of the given links I was able to solve the problem myself. The correct way is to get the resource ID with

```
getResources().getIdentifier("FILENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION",
                             "raw", getPackageName());
```

To get it as a InputStream

```
InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(
            getResources().getIdentifier("FILENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION",
            "raw", getPackageName()));
```

Comment: Just to clarify: Do **not** prepend `raw/` for the file name. Valid example: `.getIdentifier("products","raw", getPackageName());` for `res/raw/products.json`

Comment: As stated by JJD, you don't need the raw/ before the FILENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION. I found that if you wish to use the extension, for example I have two files abc.jpg and abc.zip, I will add them both to raw folder as abc_jpg and abc_zip (extensions in raw folder are ignored), then assign String variable filename = abc.jpg or abc.zip, then use InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(getResources().getIdentifier(filename.replace(".", "_"), "raw", getPackageName()));    

Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: remember to close any streams you open

Comment: i need the filepath... how can i get it instead of the inputstream?

Comment: It is not worked for localized raw folders. Any Idea??

Answer (score 52):

Here is example of taking XML file from raw folder:

```
 InputStream XmlFileInputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.taskslists5items); // getting XML
```

Then you can:

```
 String sxml = readTextFile(XmlFileInputStream);
```

when:

```
 public String readTextFile(InputStream inputStream) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        try {
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        return outputStream.toString();
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't use R.raw.XYZ because the name of XYZ is only available as a string. But the link of simon help me solve the problem. I will give a correct solution as a separate answer.

Comment: this works perfectly fine `InputStream input = Context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.configjson);`

Answer (score 15):

You can read files in raw/res using `getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myfilename)`.

BUT there is an IDE limitation that the file name you use can only contain lower case alphanumeric characters and dot. So file names like `XYZ.txt` or `my_data.bin` will not be listed in R.

Comment: underscore is also allowed in resource file names

Comment: Also numbers are allowed (not as the first character).

Comment: Not as the first character...because that would not be a valid Java variable identifier

Answer (score 5):

Here are two approaches you can read raw resources using Kotlin.

You can get it by getting the resource id. Or, you can use string identifier in which you can programmatically change the filename with incrementation.

Cheers mate

```
// R.raw.data_post

this.context.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.data_post)
this.context.resources.getIdentifier("data_post", "raw", this.context.packageName)
```