# FileInputStream FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, fileinputstream

I'm working with a library and I need to get a file path stored at raw folder, so library methods create a FileInputStream, but I always get a FileNotFoundException from library methods.

So I have created a class and try:

```
String path = "android.resource://" +context.getPackageName () + "/" + "myFileName"; 
InputStream fis2 = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myFileName);
File f = new File(path);
```

fis2 and f are correctly created and I get no FileNotFoundException.

But when I try: `FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);` I get the FileNotFoundException.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read file from res/raw by name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912825/how-to-read-file-from-res-raw-by-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to get a file path stored at raw folder

That is not possible, as it is not a file.

> so library methods create a FileInputStream

Those library methods need to be adjusted to work with an ordinary `InputStream`. Then, use your `fis2` `InputStream`.

Comment: Thank you. I have found a way to work with the library using Uris