# FTP upload does nothing

Tags: android, file, ftp

I've made an APP that Uploads a simple TXT file to a FTP server.

Errors:

Doesn't publish the onProgressUpdate TV.setText but pulbishes the onPostExecute TV.setText. (Not yet resolved)

Doesn't upload the file, no error reported, finishes very quickly. (Solved, by solving next problem)

Says it can't find the file. I'm guessing that this is not the way to call a file in /res/raw. The file does exist. -Solved with link provided by coments use:-

```
InputStream FIS = getResources().openRawResource(getResources().getIdentifier("raw/wa", "raw", getPackageName()));-
```

Code

```
private class AsyncFTP extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            publishProgress("Start");
            //Creo FTPClient
            FTPClient FTP = new FTPClient();
            //Defino datos del servidor
            String FTP_HOST = "000.000.000.000"; //Not real IP
            String FTP_USER = "usuer";
            String FTP_PASS = "pass";

            //Cargo el archivo
            File file = new File("res/raw/asd.txt"); 
            publishProgress("File selected");
            //Conectar
            try{
                publishProgress("Conecting ");
                FTP.connect(FTP_HOST,21);
                FTP.login(FTP_USER,FTP_PASS);
                publishProgress("Conected "+String.valueOf(FTP.getReplyCode()));
                FTP.type(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);


                //Directorio
                FTP.changeWorkingDirectory("/public_html/");

                publishProgress("Dir "+String.valueOf(FTP.getReplyCode()));
                FileInputStream FIS = new FileInputStream(file); //ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                FTP.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                FTP.storeFile("asd.txt",FIS);
                publishProgress("Subio"+String.valueOf(FTP.getReplyCode()));



            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String txt) {
            TV.setText(TV.getText()+"\n"+txt);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            TV.setText(TV.getText()+"\n Termino FTP");
        }
    }
```

Logcat

```
OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.12.SPL
    Build Date: 07/01/14 Tue
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: quic/kk_2.7_rb1.41
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.04.007.064 +  NOTHING
12-15 12:20:20.110    5701-5701/com.lstupenengo.mysql D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
12-15 12:20:20.240    5701-5701/com.lstupenengo.mysql I/ActivityManager﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@44bcc450 time:294619278
12-15 12:20:23.193    5701-5701/com.lstupenengo.mysql I/ActivityManager﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@44bcc450 time:294622220
12-15 12:20:36.876    5701-5701/com.lstupenengo.mysql I/ActivityManager﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@44bcc450 time:294635918
12-15 12:20:38.938    5701-6070/com.lstupenengo.mysql W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /res/raw/wa.db: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-15 12:20:38.938    5701-6070/com.lstupenengo.mysql W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:418)
12-15 12:20:38.938    5701-6070/com.lstupenengo.mysql W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
12-15 12:20:38.938    5701-6070/com.lstupenengo.mysql W/System.err﹕ at com.lstupenengo.mysql.MainActivity$AsyncFTP.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:100)
12-15 12:20:38.948    5701-6070/com.lstupenengo.mysql W/System.err﹕ at com.lstupenengo.mysql.MainActivity$AsyncFTP.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:71)
12-15 12:20:38.948    5701-6070/com.lstupenengo.mysql W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
12-15 12:20:38.948    5701-6070/com.lstupenengo.mysql W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-15 12:20:38.948    5701-6070/com.lstupenengo.mysql W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
12-15 12:20:38.948    5701-6070/com.lstupenengo.mysql W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-15 12:20:38.958    5701-6070/com.lstupenengo.mysql W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-15 12:20:38.958    5701-6070/com.lstupenengo.mysql W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-15 12:20:38.958    5701-6070/com.lstupenengo.mysql W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-15 12:20:38.958    5701-6070/com.lstupenengo.mysql W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
12-15 12:20:38.958    5701-6070/com.lstupenengo.mysql W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
12-15 12:20:38.968    5701-6070/com.lstupenengo.mysql W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:402)
12-15 12:20:38.968    5701-6070/com.lstupenengo.mysql W/System.err﹕ ... 9 more
12-15 12:20:48.007    5701-5701/com.lstupenengo.mysql I/ActivityManager﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@44bcc450 time:294647049
12-15 12:21:16.084    5701-5701/com.lstupenengo.mysql I/ActivityManager﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@44bcc450 time:294675123
```

Comment: It's failing on the finding the file. I don't this you can load the file from `res/raw` some simply as You need to load from it using something like this: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912825/how-to-read-file-from-res-raw-by-name`.

Comment: That might solve the issue with finding the file. Thank you. Do you know why I cant get any onProgressUpdate to my TextView?