# Exception caught while trying to read the file from the raw folder

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an app where I try to connect to the server through https. For this reason I have installed a self signed certificate. I have stored the certificate inside the raw folder. Now when I try to access it an exception is thrown which says "ENOENT. No such file or directory".

**Here's my code :**

```
try {
    InputStream id=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.introduceprojectssl);

    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    Uri url1 = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/introduceprojectssl");
    String Path = url1.toString();

    InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(Path));
}
catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e("Exception caught",e.getMessage();
}
```

Comment: `please be in detail`

Comment: @maven, i am not able to give the path of the file stored in the raw folder to FileInputStream

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read file from res/raw by name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912825/how-to-read-file-from-res-raw-by-name)

Comment: @maven, the above said link doesn't give the path to the raw folder in the form of string

Answer (score 0):

You are adding file name i.e `introduceprojectssl` to URI actually you should add resourse ID ie `R.raw.introduceprojectssl`

```
 Uri url1 = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+R.raw.introduceprojectssl);
```

Comment: adding the resource id gives the same exception, @Shakeeb Ayaz. I tried it

Comment: what exception you get

Comment: ENOENT. There is no such file or directory

Comment: then try Uri.parse("android.resource://your_packege_name/raw/introduceprojectssl");

Comment: one "/" is missing that should be there between package name and raw

Comment: is your package name com.example.suhai_000.delete?