# check uri for android raw file

Tags: android, file, resources, uri

i'm trying to get the URI of a file in the raw folder of my app in this way:

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.myfile);
```

or

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://mypackage/raw/myfile");
```

Then i use this method to check if the uri was correct:

```
File f = new File(myUri.toString());
    if (f.exists()) {
        Log.d("YES", "file exist");
    }
    if (!f.exists()){
        Log.d("NO", "file doesn't exist");
    }
```

But i always get: "No, file doesn't exist".

Do you know why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15934525/3541465

Answer (score 2):

First, because there is no file. Resources are files on your developer machine. They are not files on the device.

Second, because `new File(myUri.toString())` will never work. A `Uri` always has a scheme; filesystem paths never have a scheme.

Third, because even if you used `new File(myUri.getPath())`, that will work at most for a `file://` `Uri`. There are many other types of `Uri` schemes; none of them will have paths that map directly to filesystem paths. Even with a `file://` `Uri`, the filesystem path may not be one that you have direct access to (e.g., an arbitrary path on removable media on Android 4.4+).

Comment: Is there a way to check if the uri was correct, though? It's obviously what he wants to know, even if he didn't explicitly ask.

Comment: @blimpse: "Is there a way to check if the uri was correct, though?" -- use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` and see if it works. If you get an exception, the `Uri` was invalid.