# Add a ringtone (from res/raw) to android system ringtones

Tags: android, root, ringtone

I have an app that runs on a custom android tablet. I want to add a ringtone that I would include in `res/raw` folder and the app should copy it to system ringtones folder. I have root access.

I would like it to be over written in case if a ringtone with same name exists.

I tried to google for it but couldn't get any help

**UPDATE**

I have tried this code but it the file isn't moved/copied

```
try{

        InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(
                getResources().getIdentifier("ring_default",
                        "raw", getPackageName()));
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        out.writeBytes("mount -o remount,rw /system\n");
        out.writeBytes("mv "+ins.toString()+" /system/file.new\n");
        out.writeBytes("exit\n");
        out.flush();
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Update 2**
 i tried 
`out.writeBytes("mv /system/media/audio/ringtones/ring4.wav /system/media/audio/ringtones/ring5.wav\n");` and it works.

Now I need to know how I can find the path to my res/raw folder and replace it in the above case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do a process command that would copy the ringtong to the folder `/system/media/audio/ringtones`

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin thanks. How would I get the source location? res/raw/my_rigtone.wav?

Comment: Go here on how to access it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912825/how-to-read-file-from-res-raw-by-name

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin please check my updated question