# Android Studio can't find my JSON file

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I created a `raw` Android resource directory in `res` and added `cars.json` to it. It shows up on my package explorer. When I try to call

```
File file = new File("raw/cars.json")
```

I get a FileNotFoundException. I've tried using simply cars.json and even the entire path to the file but I get the same results.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have toy tried using `File file = new File("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/equipment.json");`

Comment: If your file is titled cars.json why are you loading equipment.json? Is that a typo?

Comment: try also<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912825/how-to-read-file-from-res-raw-by-name>.

Comment: here is the solution of a similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15934525/5268730

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a **resource from the raw directory** call `getResources().openRawResource(resourceName)`.

This will give you a `InputStream`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function directly:

```
private String getJsonStringFromRaw(filenmae)
{
    String jsonString = null; 
    try { 
        InputStream inputStream= getAssets().open(filename); 
        int size = inputStream.available(); 
        byte[] buffer= new byte[size]; 
        inputStream.read(buffer); 
        inputStream.close(); 
        jsonString = new String(buffer, "UTF-8"); } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        return null; 
    } 
    return jsonString; 
}
```

You can access json data by iterating through the json object below. JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(getJsonStringFronRaw("cars.json"))

Answer (score -1):

Retrieving resource from the raw directory can be achieved with openRawResources a sub class of getResources, this takes in a resource id (your json file) and returns a InputStream.

```
InputStream myInput=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.your_json);
```

If you need more info, here is the [google documention](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource(int,%20android.util.TypedValue))