# Creating File object (Android)

Tags: java, android

Please help.

I'm trying to create a File object using a directory path. Here is my code

```
String dirPath = "/app/src/main/res/xml/sample.xml";
File source = new File(dirPath);
Log.v("file test", "exists " + source.exists());
```

But the Log-message says that source (File object from my code sample) does not exist. But it does exist, I see it in my project structure.

Comment: you can try with this > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912825/how-to-read-file-from-res-raw-by-name

Comment: Resources are not files on the device; they are entries in the APK file that is your app.

Comment: Your `src` directory won't be present in the deployed application.

Comment: Problem solved. sample.xml must be placed in assets-folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sample.xml must be placed in assets-folder in order for you to be able to access it.

Comment: Thank you man, but I have already solved the problem. Look at the last comment to my question.

Comment: I see. In that case write an answer to your own question and mark your answer as solved.