# File not found exception while trying to get the video uri from res->raw Folder in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have the below code to get the video(glass.avi) from res->raw folder in Android studio and save to sd card. But it is showing file not found exception.

```
 vuri= Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.glass);
        OutputStream out;

        try
        {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(String.valueOf(vuri)));

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int n;
            while (-1 != (n = fis.read(buf)))
                stream.write(buf, 0, n);

            byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();




        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/";
        File createDir = new File(root+"master"+File.separator);
        createDir.mkdir();


        File file = new File(root + "master" + File.separator +"master.avi");

        file.createNewFile();
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        out.write(bytes);
        out.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It must be in a supported format (3gp, wmv, mp4 )

Comment: avi is also supported format.

Comment: [The official list of supported video formats](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html#core)

Comment: I have tried with avi, mp4, wmv, all are not working. Anyway, here the issue is with the uri irrespective of format.

Comment: Your **URI** format is correct, the raw folder must be inside the res folder, otherwise it won't work. check this out

Comment: And change `FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(String.valueOf(vuri)));` into this `FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(vuri.getPath()));`

Comment: it is inside res

Comment: tried with vuri.getPath(), still the same error.

Comment: What happens if you use `getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.glass)` instead of building the `Uri` manually?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read file from res/raw by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912825/how-to-read-file-from-res-raw-by-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked with the below code.

```
getResources().getIdentifier("FILENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION",
                             "raw", getPackageName());
```

To get it as a InputStream

```
InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(
            getResources().getIdentifier("FILENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION",
            "raw", getPackageName()));
```

Comment: Hello, I am getting the same error while getting sound file for push notification from raw folder. How did you converted this InputStream to a uri?