# How to connect to private url with private ssl certificate

Tags: java, android, ssl-certificate, trustmanager

I am trying to connect my android app to a url belonging to a private company in order to retrieve and send information. When I do so however I receive an error Trust anchor for certification path not found, the ssl certificate for the url is valid though, I did research and I used the following code I used to trust the certificate in a class Http TrustManager

```
         public class HttpsTrustManager {
public void trust() throws CertificateException, IOException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

    InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("load-der.crt"));
    Certificate ca;
    try {
        ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
        out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
    } finally {
        caInput.close();
    }

    String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
    keyStore.load(null, null);
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

    String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
    tmf.init(keyStore);


    SSLContext context = null;
    try {
        context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext
    URL url = new URL("https://systems.syspearl.com/api");
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection =
            (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
    InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    IOUtils.copyStream(in,out);

}
```

And this is how I call it in the main activity

```
       new HttpsTrusrtManger().trust();
```

This doesn't work however. Please render necessary help

Comment: Did you load your certificate in place of load-der.crt?

Comment: No I did not, I do have the certificate though In res/raw/my_ca, how would I load in place of load-Der.crt?

Comment: You need to get the server certificate and store in assests folder or somewhere and then load it. Google for getting server certificate. Also there is whole documentation on android dev site using opnessl

Comment: I have the certificate in res file, how would I load it in place of load-Der.crt?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912825/how-to-read-file-from-res-raw-by-name

Comment: also in newer version you should follow https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

Comment: When I use getResources in the class it says cannot resolve symbol 'get Resources'

Comment: it needs a context. you need to pass context from somewhere. al;so if you use network config https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO28771.html use opnssl and get the sha256 and add it in xml

Comment: Alright let me try it out

Comment: It failed to work, I am still getting the same trust anchor error

Comment: Is the certificate supposed to be added to android studio as an xml file?