# Kotlin MediaPlayer simple usage

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

I'm new to Kotlin and am trying to make a simple AudioManager (wrapping MediaPlayer).

I want the class to play the audio.

Here is my class:

```
package com.example.myappname

import android.media.MediaPlayer

interface AudioManagerInput {
    fun startSound()
    fun stopSound()
}

class AudioManager: AudioManagerInput {

    // Instance variables

    private var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null

    // AudioManagerInput methods

    override fun startSound() {
        if (mediaPlayer == null) {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
            mediaPlayer?.setDataSource("R.raw.songone") // ???
        }
        mediaPlayer?.start()
    }

    override fun stopSound() {
        mediaPlayer?.stop()
    }
}
```

I'm having issues setting the song.

I'm looking to load a local file `R.raw.songone` which is a .wav file sitting in `res/raw`.

How can I get a String to it's path?

I've scoured tutorials which hold other solutions to using MediaPlayer but have had issues with not knowing what to import, not being able to call `create`, or `context` not being found (whatever that is).

Comment: Would this go into the MainActivity.kt file, or separate class/file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import Context into AudioManager:

```
import android.content.Context
```

Modify class or it's method signature like this:

```
class AudioManager(private val context: Context): AudioManagerInput
```

Now we can pass context to `MediaPlayer`:

```
override fun startSound() {
    if (mediaPlayer == null) {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.yourSound);
    }
    mediaPlayer?.start()
}
```

To init your AudioManager from an Activity:

```
var audioManager = AudioManager(this)
```

To manually access `raw` files: [Read/write from res/raw by name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15934525/9968399).

Comment: How do I pass in the context from the calling class? `class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()`

Comment: `AudioManager(this)`

Comment: I have created like in this way and my object is cleared a few seconds with GC, keeping object static with   companion object {
                 var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null
        } is solved. fyi..

Comment: Not a good approach, I don't know how you are using the object, judging from your comment I would rather move it to a foreground service.