# Set Background Drawable Resource from String

Tags: java, android, string, drawable

I have looked everywhere but cannot find an example of programmatically setting a background resource from a string value?

As an example:

```
Drawable a = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.a );
Drawable b = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.b );
Drawable c = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.c );
abc.setBackgroundResource("b");
```

Is this possible or would I have to do it as a big switch statement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic Resource Loading Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648942/dynamic-resource-loading-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have `getResources().getIdentifier` for this purpose. It returns the id of the resources from its name.

E.g.:

```
 int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("b", "drawable", getPackageName());
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) you can find the documentation.

Comment: Oh wow, you learn something new everyday, had no idea! Thanks for your answer, I will accept as soon as I am able to :-)