# set image with setImageResource in Android Studio using a variable

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio, imageview

I am trying to set my image in my ImageView through a variable (item is the variable name, which I will be setting to lowerCase).
However, it is not working and resID will return 0.

Here is my code:

```
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imgView);

    if (item != null) {
        Log.i("item: ", item.toLowerCase());

        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(item.toLowerCase(), "drawable", "package.name");

        Log.i("resid: ", String.valueOf(resID)); //will return 0 - im guessing this is where the problem is

        iv.setImageResource(resID);
    }
```

I used this as a guide [Android, reference things in R.drawable. using variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941304/android-reference-things-in-r-drawable-using-variables) but none of the other solutions work for me, in fact they all gave me the same result (returning 0). 
I can provide more code if needed (just didn't want it to be bombastic).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `"package.name"` is wrong. use `getPackageName()`. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449692/set-background-drawable-resource-from-string) an example

Comment: @Blackbelt indeed ahh.. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getIdentifier() Returns 0 if no such resource was found. (0 is not a valid resource ID.)

and you should `getPackageName()` method of the `context` object which always return the correct package name.

if you will show your folder stracture and file's names i can help you to fix it.

btw, if you can get the drawable directly from the resource you can just use `R.drawable.resName`

Comment: It works T_T I'm so mad at myself for not figuring that out. Thank you so much! 
Yeah I know about the resource but unfortunately it wasn't an option for this app :)